# Can a person die before death time?

Tags: death

This question arised in my mind after I read - [Will Athma get moksha if a person die unnaturally?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2985/467),

Many people went from serious accident & surgery that time elder says that *Ram Rakhe ene kon chakhe* (meaning When Lord Rama is taking care of a human then even death can't harm him/her easily) or sometimes elder says that may be his death time is still not arrived that's why he/she got saved or sometimes it is called *chamatkar* (miracle).

Does this means that a person's death time is predefined when he takes birth?

If this is true then can a person die before his death time?

Comment: I don't get it that how we can possibly think that someone died before time? May be he was meant to die in that way at that particular time

Comment: @Mr.Alien Exactly, see the linked question's last words **person die unnaturally** put me to thought like this.

Comment: @Kedarnath, I think the linked question is wrong, there should be mukti in place of moksha

Comment: @Mr.K, You should write this comment below that question or you can also suggest edit on that question.

Comment: Yes person can die before time if he commits Sucide, or if he is Murdered

Answer (score 3):

### I once had a short Out-of-body Experience.

**So was I dead in the moments!?** No! Because my attachments with my body were still not broken.

The Hindu concept *Mrityu* is NOT just when the physical body stops working. Its a also **includes** when the ***Jeevatma* moves on**, breaking all its bondages, to its next stop in any other *Loka*, that could be again on this earth, based on its accumulated *Krama*.

**Hindu *Mrityu* = Body dies + *Jeevatma* moves on, breaking all its attachments.**

So they are the attachments that binds a *Jeevatma* with the body. Sages who have power "*Ichha Mrityu*" leave the body as well as attachments at the same time.

According the GREAT sage Manu, the last two stage in a CORRECT Hindu Life are:

- *VaanPrastha Aashram*: **To break the attachments of Family, Society and Past**, by moving to a jungle away form loved ones, but with just wife.
- *Sanyaas Aashram*: **To break the attachments from the body itself**, by becoming a wandering ascetic.

But as time passed on, humans degraded and the attachments with body grew stronger, so much that in *Kaliyuga*, sometimes even the Last ashram becomes insufficient to release the soul free. (Usually, people don't even follow these *Aashrams*.) And a Hindu family was made obligated for *PINDA DAAN* and other *Sanskaars* of its dead, for their *shanti*. In some cases, even after *Pinda Daan*, the *Pitra-Dosha* may remain attached to a person from birth to birth, causing him recurring losses, in his every life.

(In fact, of all the adversaries a person may face in Life, are MOSTLY due to unsatisfied soul of *Pitra* or ancestors.)

Now question is, **what happens in *Akaal Mrityu*?** That is when the time of *Mrityu* i.e end of bondage, hasn't come but still the body dies due to some accident.

*Akaal Mrityu* is also due to *Karma*, when its written that the soul has to wander in *BhootYoni*. That is between two worlds, or its two "stops". Due to INTENSE attachments even after death rituals, the soul may not gets "shanti" in that case.

*"Chamatkaars"* are only for a expecting souls. **But, in fact everything is ALREADY written**, i.e when is the body gonna die and when are its attachments gonna break.

Answer (score 1):

Namaste

A person's destiny is fixed by number of breath, hence our Yoga is all about breath control and the way forward to increase longevity.  More food in stomach more oxygen required through breathing, so person likely to die before his age !

A human being has family, takes birth within a community, community lives in a society, society lives in a state then country....etc..  All of them collectively contribute to the good or bad karma and this in turn may increase or decrease the life span.

Bhagirath did penance and brought mother Ganga to earth and also brought salvation to all his ancestors, who were "burnt to ashes", there getting blessing from "pitrus" and also longevity.

It is in recorded history that Mughal emperor prayed for his son Akbar's life in return Babar himself expired shortly afterwards, while Akbar survived to rule till his old age... Akbar with no options gave away his kingdom to the spoilt kid Humayun of anarkali fame.

There are many instances in recorded history, where parents prayed and increased children's longevity and vice-versa.

Those knowledge in jyotisha sastra would be able to throw much more light with evidences.  Prayers help in increasing longevity (Mahamrityunjaya mantra).

The elder brothers of Lord Krishna for various other known reasons, had to die in hands of his Uncle Kamsa i.e. brought sorrow to their parents (Devaki-Vasudeva), whereas Lord Krishna brought relief, release, ananda & moksha to his parents.

Children born during month of April, when planet Sun is exalted is likely to give longevity to parents, while births in October, when Sun is debilitated may reduce longevity

That is why in India, there are certain beliefs on children born during amavasya, purnima (mother's longevity issues), eclipse period (lunar / solar), lunar = mother longevity, solar -father's longevity.   This has astrological basis and astrology is one of the limbs of Vedas.

In short, family, community, society, state & country shall determine the fate of an individual, at the same time living style, individual karma & family/ parents karma also contribute to longevity.

Comment: Your answer needs little correction about Mughal paragraph. Babar's son was Humayun and Humayun' son was Akbar. Akbar's son was Salim/Jehangir who is famous for Anarkali. However, Anarkali's story is said to be a work of fiction and not real. Btw, answers in this site needs to be cited with reliable texts or site references. So, either put references in your answers or instead of answers mention them in question comments