# What happens to the soul of a person who died unnaturally in an accident?

Tags: vishnu, bhagavad-gita, garuda-purana, naraka, swarga

If a religious, generous, kind-hearted person dies unnaturally in an accident what happens to its soul?
The person had done great works in his life of 46 years and on the second hand, he was a businessman and always had many worries/problems related to work and family. I didn't find the answer I require in any other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will the atma get moksha if a person dies unnaturally?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2985/will-the-atma-get-moksha-if-a-person-dies-unnaturally)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I don't think it's a duplicate. Question is asking what happens to soul of a person who dies unnaturally, no mention of specific outcome like Moksha. But Be Happy's answer on that question does answer this question as well.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria This is a duplicate. This user has asked almost the same question yesterday as well and then self deleted. Sorry for his loss.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma The question you have linked is about Moksha which is not what this question is about. This question is simply asking what happens to soul in case of unnatural death.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria It is asking what happens viz will it get moksha or anything and the answer also addresses it. This would only get repeated answers.  Same question was asked by the OP which is now self deleted. This is almost a repost. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/32424/5212

Comment: I didn't find the answer that I require, in any previous question

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Moksha is not the only thing that comes out of death. That question specifically asks whether or not atma will get Moksha which can be answered in yes or no. This question simply asking what happens and Moksha word also may not be mentioned in any answer if posted. Repeated answer is fine if it can be applied to this question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not that easy to answer:
It doesn't depend on whether the death is natural or unnatural.

Gita gives a clue about this.

Soul moves to next destination

वासांसि जीर्णानि यथा विहाय
नवानि गृह्णाति नरोऽपराणि।
तथा शरीराणि विहाय जीर्णा
न्यन्यानि संयाति नवानि देही

2.22 As after rejecting wornout clothes a man takes up other new ones, likewise after rejecting wornout bodies the embodied one unites with other new ones.

Where soul goes depends and even that is not so easy to say

यं यं वापि स्मरन्भावं त्यजत्यन्ते कलेवरम्।
तं तमेवैति कौन्तेय सदा तद्भावभावितः
8.6 On whatever sphere of being the mind of a man may be intent at the time of death, thither he will go.

गहना कर्मणो गतिः
4.17: for mysterious is the law of action

ऊर्ध्वं गच्छन्ति सत्त्वस्था मध्ये तिष्ठन्ति राजसाः।
जघन्यगुणवृत्तिस्था अधो गच्छन्ति तामसाः
14.18 People who conform to sattva go higher up; those who conform to rajas stay in the middle; those who conform to tamas, who conform to the actions of the lowest ality, go down.

Don't worry. If he did good karma, he will get good birth as per above Gita verses. Just do post death rituals nicely.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: No, sorry, it does not provide any answer at all. Kindly focus on thenword unnatural