# What is Astrology and what are its benefits?

Tags: astrology

1. What kind of questions can an astrologer answer (or predict the results) correctly?
2. What are the different types of astrology?

   - Do all of them give accurate results?
   - Which among them is mostly used today and why?

Comment: Somewhat Related: [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-predetermined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma) and [Does “Free Will” really exist, even if universe repeats itself in perfect pattern?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10911/does-free-will-really-exist-even-if-universe-repeats-itself-in-perfect-patter). ..... If we believe the past/present/future to be predetermined then the predicting becomes moot.

Comment: @Subbu Ur question too broad IMO..Vedic Jyotish basically deals with the 12 bhavas -From Lagna(1st bhava) till the Dwadasa Bhava(12th)..And each of them has some significance (karakatwa) or the other..for ex-Lagna is one oneself one's body..so an astrologer can predict about u about ur body...2nd bhava  denotes ur family..so he can predict about ur family...3rd bhava denotes ur siblings..so he can predict how many brother sisters u will hve and all sorts of allied questions...similarly 7th house deals with ur spouse,the married life,business prospects...

Comment: ---6th house diseases...8th house death etc etc ...so basically a good astrologer can answer **any** of ur  queries ..

Comment: However the remaining questions are good and answerable..