# Is the feeling of "Deja Vu", a glimpse of self realization?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, bhagavad-gita, atma, identification-request

As per below post, a philosophy called "Eternal Return" states that all events are repeating infinitely & hence predetermined.
[Does "Free Will" really exist, even if universe repeats itself in perfect pattern?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10911/1049)

However, one cannot remember what's going to happen or happened in the past, unless one's destiny is determined to know that info at that moment.
Once a person knows that the events happening around him/her, are happening by themselves & the Self is not the doer,  then that's "**Self realization**".

> BG 5.8, 5.9 — "'I' certainly don't do anything" is believed by knower of fundamentals (tattva gyAna) - even while seeing, hearing, touching, smelling, eating, moving, dreaming, breathing, talking, discarding, accepting, opening, closing; -- "Senses only are acting in the subjects of senses" - is understood.

A while back, in this context, I had come across following phenomenon:

> [**Déjà vu**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu) (/ˌdeɪʒɑː ˈvuː/) is the feeling that the situation currently being experienced has already been experienced in the past. Déjà vu is a feeling of familiarity, and *déjà vécu* (the feeling of having "already lived through" something) is a feeling of recollection.

Being part of *Atman* (the self or the supreme One), surely many of us would have had this feeling at various points of life.The feeling goes away in moments.

**Question**:
Is "Deja Vu" a form of Self realization? (any scripture supports that)

Comment: "However, *one cannot remember what's going to happen* ( or happened in the past...," Are you sure even future events are hidden (in dormant state) in our memory like past births? Do you know any scriptures which say this?

Comment: @TheDestroyer, that sentence means, if at given moment a person is not destined to recall the future event (whether stored in memory or hidden in dormant), then that person cannot remember. Regarding scripture, there might be many indirect references (like above), however the prominent one is an excerpt which I have heard from childhood: "Without the will of BrahmA, not even a leaf can move." Anyways that statement is just in a side context.

Comment: How can Deja Vu be self realisation feeling. In deja vu when you are doing something like reading a page on book while drinking coffee, suddenly you will feel as if you just did it a few days or few moments earlier. You feel as if you had just read that page in book while drinking coffee, where in fact you had not actually done it . It does not seem like a self realisation thing. By the way, have you ever had deja vu ?

Comment: @AnuragSingh, Your first statement is, kind of my Qn. BTW, "Deja Vu" has the feeling of repeating something, but not few days or moments before. One just feels that the things are repeating. Yes, since childhood, I had many instances of "Deja Vu" and most of the people have it. It's a common phenomenon. Why am I associating "Deja Vu" with "Self Realisation"? It's because, both lead to the same concept of *KAla Chakra*.